# typescript : how to loop the object present in unknown type. Please see the sample code

Tags: typescript

```
interface Response{
  statusCode: number;
  body?: unknown | undefined;
}
const response:Response={
  statusCode: 200,
  body: {
    access_token: {
      token: '123456789012345566',
      seconds_to_expire: null
    }
  }
}

From the above code , how can i get the token value.I tried some options but failed to get the `token` value because the body is of type `unknown`.
```

i tried to get the values using Object.keys(), forEach() loop , but not getting the token value

Comment: If you're using typescript 4.9, you can use `if('access_token' in response.body && 'token' in response.body.access_token) {...}` I think. Otherwise you might need to create a type predicate https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

Comment: tried the above solution its not working @ShamPooSham

Comment: Did you try with type predicate too?